# Numerical String Conversions in Python Function

Tags: python, string

I'm currently learning python so I apologize in advance for the messiness of my code. My function is meant to take in a single string and add the string numbers together. i.e. A string argument of 123 will become 1 + 2 + 3 and return 6.
My issue is  when I iterate through my list - python keeps indicating that the variable has been referenced before any value has been assigned. However when I print out the values being calculated they are correct. Even more confusing is that when I return them - they are incorrect. I can't seem to work out where I'm going wrong. Could anyone tell me what the issue may be?

Thank you!

```
listy = []
global total 
#Convert number to a list then cycle through the list manually via elements     and add them all up
def digit_sum(x):
    number= []
    number.append(x)
    print number 

    for i in range(len(number)):
        result = str(number[i])
        print result

        #Now it has been converted to a string so we should be able to
        #read each number separately now and re-convert them to integers
        for i in result:
            listy.append(i)
            print listy
            #listy is printing [5,3,4]

        for i in listy:
           total += int(i)
           return total

print digit_sum(x)
```

Comment: Could anyone let me know why this was down-voted? I'm still new to stack overflow so was there a reason for this down vote? Was it lack of clarity..?

Comment: You have the right concept but it could be done cleaner by using other built-in functions. 

One thing I notice is your `return` statement is nested in the last for loop. You'll want to un-indent it so it's not called each time the loop iterates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have worked out what was wrong with my code. As I am still new to Python, I made some very novice mistakes such as not realizing declaring a variable outside the local function would result in the solution not being what I had expected.

Due to my returns being placed incorrectly as well as my listy [] variable being instantiated outside my function, instead of reading each number once, it would read it three times.

This has now been corrected in the code below.

```
    #Convert number to a list then cycle through the list manually via elements and add them all up
def digit_sum(x):
    total = 0
    number= []
    number.append(x)
    print number 

    for i in range(len(number)):
        result = str(number[i])
        print result

        #Now it has been converted to a string so we should be able to
        #read each number separately now and re-convert them to integers

        for i in result:
            listy = []
            listy.append(i)
            # print listy
            #listy is printing [5,3,4]

            for i in listy:
               print i
               total+= int(i)
               print total
               break

    return total

print digit_sum(111)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure what's going on in your code there, especially with the messed up indentation, but your problem is easily sovled:

```
sum(map(int, str(534)))
```

It makes the number a string, then converts each digit to an `int` with `map`, then just sums it all.

Comment: I'm still learning Python now - I apologize for the indentation. I'll fix it now.
But the 534 is just to test the function - it can be any numerical string argument.

Comment: Hi Maltysen, Thanks for your approach. What do you find confusing about my code?

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is only about summing a string of numbers, then list comprehension itself would do or as @Maltysen suggested you could use map

```
sum([int(x) for x in "534"])
```

Answer (score 0):

pretty simple:
You can use a map or a list comprehension. They are pretty much equivalent. Other people gave an answer using map but I decided to use a list comprehension.

```
s = "1234567"
sum([int(character) for character in s])
```